# Angularjs redirect after $http response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code, I hope it is clear enough and my question is,
How can I wait until the success response from $http and only redirect to `/path`?

```
service.foo().then(function(response){
 $http.get('/url').success(function(response){
  if (response) {
   setTimeout(function(){alert(response)}, 5000);//
  } else {
   //do something and redirect
  }
  $location.path('/path); //How can I wait until the response and just redirect?
 });
});
```

You can see I set a time out for 5secs to alert the response. In my testing, the page redirect to `/path` and then only alert the response. 
What I want is delay 5secs then alert then redirect.

Comment: why dont you move your location.path code inside success function call of $http

Comment: it actually inside success function. Just no mater what conditions it will always preforms redirect. But my problem is, I want to wait until $http response and just perform redirect

Comment: It seems to me that this code already does what you're asking. It will wait until a successful response from '/url', and then redirect to '/path'.

Comment: @jmr Hi, I edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: The delay happens AFTER the successful response.. what you wnat is already happening. If you want success -> timeout -> alert -> redirect, just put your redirect within the timeout function

Comment: You can always `$broadcast` an event and listen for it.... But as everyone else said, there is no need for that as your redirect already waits for the success function before executing.

Comment: @TiagoRoldão  thankyou i got what you meant

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.location='#pagename';
```

Answer (score 0):

$location.path('/path); put in setTimeout.

Answer (score -1):

```
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/someUrl'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      // this callback will be called asynchronously
      // when the response is available redirect
      //$location.path()
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      // or server returns response with an error 
    });
```